# export a dict of all key/pair values from Prefect Cloud

Tags: prefect

I'm wondering if there's an easy way to export all key/pair values in Prefect cloud. Can't find anything in the docs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build some bash script to automate that process using those commands:

```bash
prefect kv list
prefect kv get foo
```

Maybe this way?

```bash
for kv in `prefect kv list`; do prefect kv get "$kv"; done
```

Comment: gave me `No keys found` which isn't the case...but that's a start! thanks!